# Why "HTML <input type='file' />" has "files" property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

Consider this HTML snippet:

```
<input type='file' id='fileUpload' />
```

To get access to this control in JavaScript, we can write:

```
var temp = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
```

OK, don't get mad, I know you all know this. But the interesting part is that, `temp` variable now has a property called `files`, (not **file**, but **files**, the plural form) which is of type `FileList`, which of course is a list of `File` objects. This **semantically** should mean that uploading multiple files via **one and only one** HTML file upload control should be possible. However, you can't upload multiple files this way and there are many workarounds, not straight usage.

How do you explain this paradox?

Update: I built this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/kMPTF/3/) to see one of the answers in action.

Comment: If the file input was named like an array (e.g. `file[]`), then will the files all go into one `FileList`?

Comment: @Dani, I really become happy to hear a good news from you. I thought that it is impossible. But I really adore to hear that it's **possible**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML5, The multiple attribute specifies that multiple values can be selected for an input field.

```
<input type='file' multiple='multiple' />
```

These links should help:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_attributes.asp

http://rakaz.nl/2009/08/uploading-multiple-files-using-html5.html

Comment: I just got exited to see that. So, technically this means that multiple files would be sent via HTTP Post, yeah?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileList), it is only applicable when using the file upload element via drag-n-drop.

Comment: No, that's not true. It says "It's **also** used" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

So that we can read on the client the contents of files selected that way:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications

This is possible in Firefox since version 3.0. At the time I've written an extensive article on how to do real Ajax file uploads: http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

Nowadays, the Firefox 3.0 API has been removed. Instead you should be using a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) together with a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object. This should work in most recent browser version. I haven't done extensive research, but I believe no version of IE implements anything of these yet.